# Update Statement in mysql procedure in not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, java-stored-procedures

Here is my procedure code. I am trying to update Username by putting old username in where clause.but it doesn't work.

```
 DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `databasename`.`UpdateUsername` $$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdateUsername`
(IN  uname   VARCHAR(30),tid  VARCHAR(100),username VARCHAR(30)  )

BEGIN



UPDATE table_name SET Username=username WHERE Username=uname;

END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

please help me to FIX this problem.

Comment: no errors found ,doesnt update the value.

Comment: Mahmoud Gamal  yes not its working..

Comment: instead of comment answer me i ll accept it..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove 'username' from line number '6' and use some other parameter name. It might be conflicting with your table Username field. 
For example: `UPDATE table_name SET Username=OTHER_PARAMETER_NAME WHERE Username=uname;`

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have faced same issue give an alise to table name and try running update query

try this query

```
UPDATE table_name  tn SET tn.Username=username WHERE tn.Username=uname;
```

the query i have used is  :

```
update file_structure fs set fs.active_status = 'N' where fs.fileid = temp_fileid and fs.appid = temp_appid;
```

Answer (score 0):

If tid is the table name, shouldn't you use tid instead of table_name in the update query?

Comment: "tid" is another column name its not table_name.